# VS2013 Express Error: namespace is not recognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, namespaces, nuget

I have three projects: BLL, DAL and mycv. after to reference DAL inside BLL, BLL inside mycv, I tried to call a funcion installed inside BLL which is existing.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express, MVC5, AngularJS (I added as nuget) and JQuery libraries (I added as nuget).

I installed Target Framework as 4.0 version.

When I use using BLL, the namespace is not recognized.

I give you the structure of my solution and you'll see all the references:

[image]

DAL code is:

```
public class DatosPersonales
{
    public Entities.DatosPersonales getDatosPersonales_DAL()
    {   
        return new Entities.DatosPersonales();
    }
}
```

BLL code is:

```
public class DatosPersonales
{
    public Entities.DatosPersonales getDatosPersonales()
    {
        return DAL.DatosPersonales();
    }
}
```

Finally, in mycv project I call BLL class of DatosPersonales:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var clase = new DatosPersonales();                
    return View();
}
```

With that error I can not compile succesfully.

If you need something more to add let me know and I will give you more information.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that your DAL layer i building successfully. Try cleaning the layers and build them one by one. First DAL, then BLL and finally the main layer.

Sometimes if your most inner layer (or DAL in your case) doesn't compiles successfully, it affects the other layers as well.

Comment: I cleaned and building individually and the same error. when I clean mycv is okay but when I build it is giving me the same error

Comment: Ok. Have you tried creating any another sample project, with just two projects where one will be substitute for BLL and another for the main project ? Try using the same classes which u added in actual project. Another thing i would suggest is check out the namespace which get's formed for any class you added in BLL layer.

Comment: nothing, the same error, I created tttt and I added DAL and BLL project I cleaned and build individually and I added BLL reference inside tttt project. I am getting same error. About name spaces they are ok.

Comment: Try adding another project and add it's reference in the main project. This will rule out the scenario that whether this is issue with your BLL project only or it is with all.

Comment: okay, it is working with a new Classlibrary1 Project but I had to restart the laptop. Maybe some dirty things in memory but with BLL is not working. Anyway I did so several changes in project that I think I will create a new BLL project... Thanks Tech Jay